# Error in PostGIS intersection

Tags: postgis, postgresql, intersection, st-intersects

I have a PostGIS query that counts the length of individual lines in each buffer:

```
SELECT 
   buffered.name, 
   ST_LENGTH(ST_Intersection(buffered.buffer, lines.wkb_geometry)) AS total_length 
 FROM 
   buffered, lines  
WHERE ST_Intersects(buffered.buffer, lines.wkb_geometry) 
GROUP BY buffered.name, buffered.buffer, lines.wkb_geometry
```

On one table of lines, the query runs successfully, but with a different one, psql throws the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error performing intersection: InterruptedException: Interrupted!
```

I have tried everything, I validated geometries on both tables with `ST_MakeValid()` and dropped lines from the table that have 0 length.

If both geometries are valid, how is it possible to get an error performing an intersection and what could be going wrong? Is there a way to skip the errors? Note: `buffered.buffer` is of type geometry

**Other important info:** the query seems to run endlessly in psql:  after about an hour, I cancelled the query and this is the message that was returned:

```
Cancel request sent
ERROR:  Error performing intersection: InterruptedException: Interrupted!
```

If I cancel the request after 5 or 10 minutes, no such error occurs and the log only shows

`Cancel request sent ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request`

Comment: I have never seen this error -- which almost certainly comes from GEOS. You might  have to post the actual geometries, so that people can test, and also state your OS, results of `SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version()`; and anyting else that might be relevant.

Comment: The error is from psql.  The queries ran for about an hour, then I decided to cancel it and the following was returned: `^Cancel request sent
ERROR:  Error performing intersection: InterruptedException: Interrupted!`

Comment: `POSTGIS="2.2.2 r14797" GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.1, 04 March 2015" GDAL="GDAL 1.11.2, released 2015/02/10 GDAL_DATA not found" LIBXML="2.9.2" LIBJSON="0.12" RASTER`   and Operating System is macOS 10.12.1 - the geometries are too large to post.  Is there a way to log on which record the error is happening? ?

Comment: So this error is pretty much unrelated to your problem? Please [edit] the question to clarify that the issue is a long-running query; please also include the query plan specified by EXPLAIN, and an indication of which indexes are available.

Comment: Please do not add critical information as comments. Those details belong within the question. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for information.

Comment: How is it unrelated? It is the only way I found out that there is a problem.  The query runs endlessly.   When it is cancelled early, after 5 or 10 minutes, no such error appears.  When it is cancelled later, the error appears.  I will include this info.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like postgis is getting into endless loop because of some weird geom and after while is just canceling query to not kill your machine. How many rows you got in each table?

Here's what you can do:

- run basic select query that involve geometry on each table separately. Could be something like:

> SELECT ST_BUFFER(buffered.buffer, 5) buffer FROM buffered

- If one query run forever you will identify on which table you got problem.
- If both selection works fine check EPSG of both geometry.
- Try to split your query into smaller one to catch issue. You can run for example:

> SELECT ST_Intersects(buffered.buffer, lines.wkb_geometry) FROM buffered, lines

- If you got big tables you can try to split table into chunks and add spatial indexes

Without the sample data is hard to guess what is causing the error.

Comment: Edit your query so that result contains fids and run it with "limit" by increasing "offset" and you may find the geometries which make trouble.

Comment: `SELECT ST_Intersects(buffered.buffer, lines.wkb_geometry) FROM buffered, lines` ran with no errors

Comment: `SELECT ST_Length(ST_Intersection(buffered.buffer, lines.wkb_geometry)) FROM buffered, lines` runs endlessly

Comment: There are 1371 records in `lines` and 2303 records in `buffered`

Comment: try to do it without st_length , combaing this 2 methods looks weird as st_intersection - returns a geometry that represents the shared portion of geomA and geomB. And what you trying to achive is "counts the length of individual lines in each buffer: "  So what you really counting is the length of new geometry of shared portion of line and buffer

Comment: so what should the query look like without `ST_LENGTH` ?  I am precisely trying to count the total length of lines within each buffer